# JdbcDaoSupport queryForList slow

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm trying to make a simple servlet to display some data from my database using spring framework JdbcDaoSupport. Executing one single "SELECT"-sql command takes up about 25-35 seconds. And Im pretty new to spring and i don't get why this takes so long...

Here is my code:
BeanBox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
">

        <!-- Data access related beans-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>Settings.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="productAnalyticsDAO" class="productAnalyticsDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

products.java (the actual servlet)

```
public class products extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("start:" + System.nanoTime());

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("BeanBox.xml");

        System.out.println("context created from xml:" + System.nanoTime());
        productAnalyticsDAO productDAO  = (productAnalyticsDAO) context.getBean("productAnalyticsDAO");

        System.out.println("getbean for the DAO:" + System.nanoTime());
        String interval = request.getParameterMap().isEmpty()? "today" : request.getParameter("t");

        System.out.println("fetch time parameter from request:" + System.nanoTime());

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet products</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Product analytics : " + interval.toUpperCase() + "</h1>");
            out.println("<a href=\"products?t=today\">Today</a>, ");
            out.println("<a href=\"products?t=1D\">Yesterday</a>, ");
            out.println("<a href=\"products?t=WEEKEND\">Weekend</a>, ");
            out.println("<a href=\"products?t=1W\">1 Week</a>, ");
            out.println("<a href=\"products?t=1M\">1 Month</a>, ");
            out.println("<a href=\"products?t=3M\">3 Month</a>, ");
            out.println("<a href=\"products?t=YTD\">Year To Date</a>, ");
            out.println("<a href=\"products?t=1Y\">1 Year</a>, ");
            out.println("<a href=\"products?t=3Y\">3 Year</a>");
            out.println("<table>");
            System.out.println("HTML print 1:" + System.nanoTime());
            List sales = productDAO.getProducts(interval);
            System.out.println("Fetched sqles list:" + System.nanoTime());
            for (Iterator iterator = sales.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                out.println("<tr>");
                LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap next = (LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap) iterator.next();
                out.println("<td>" + next.get("REFERENCE") + "</td>");
                out.println("<td>" + next.get("NAME") + "</td>");
                out.println("<td>" + next.get("UNITS") + "</td>");
                out.println("</tr>");
            }
            System.out.println("Print data:" + System.nanoTime());
            out.println("</table>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

productAnalyticsDAO.java (The Data access object)

```
public class productAnalyticsDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport {
    public List<String[]> getProducts(String interval){
        System.out.println("Entered getProducts:" + System.nanoTime());
        String sql = "SELECT PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, "
                + "PRODUCTS.NAME, "
                + "PRODUCTS.CATEGORY, "
                + "SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS UNITS, "
                + "SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS * TICKETLINES.PRICE) AS TOTAL "
                + "FROM RECEIPTS, "
                + "TICKETS, "
                + "TICKETLINES, "
                + "PRODUCTS "
                + "WHERE RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID "
                + "AND TICKETS.ID = TICKETLINES.TICKET "
                + "AND TICKETLINES.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID ";
                if(interval.equals("today")){
                    sql += "AND DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW)= CURDATE() ";
                }
                if(interval.equals("1D")){
                    sql += "AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW) ";
                }
                if(interval.equals("1W")){
                    sql += "AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) <= DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW) ";
                }
                if(interval.equals("WEEKEND")){
                    sql += "AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) <= DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW) ";
                    sql += "AND DAYOFWEEK(DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW))=1 OR DAYOFWEEK(DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW))=7 ";
                }
                if(interval.equals("1M")){
                    sql += "AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) <= DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW) ";
                }
                if(interval.equals("3M")){
                    sql += "AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH) <= DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW) ";
                }
                if(interval.equals("YTD")){
                    sql += "AND YEAR(RECEIPTS.DATENEW)= YEAR(CURDATE()) <= DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW) ";
                }
                if(interval.equals("1Y")){
                    sql += "AND  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) <= DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW) ";
                }
                if(interval.equals("3Y")){
                    sql += "AND  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 YEAR) <= DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW) ";
                }
                sql += "AND NOT PRODUCTS.CATEGORY = \"9286649c-00e1-428a-bd45-b47a1e0154b4\" " // filter out ophaal uren
                + "GROUP BY PRODUCTS.CATEGORY, PRODUCTS.NAME "
                + "ORDER BY PRODUCTS.NAME";

        System.out.println("Builded SQL string:" + System.nanoTime());
        List myBook = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);
        System.out.println("Fetched data:" + System.nanoTime());
        return myBook;
    }
```

I'm using System.nanoTime() to calculate the arcs between different points:

- context created from xml:4943507136673
- getbean for the DAO:4943507261046  //-> arc : 0.124373 milliseconds
- fetch time parameter from request:4943507687437 //-> arc : 0.426391 milliseconds
- HTML print 1:4943507916077 //-> arc : 0.228640 milliseconds
- Entered getProducts:4943507993097 //-> arc : 0.077020 milliseconds
- Builded SQL string:4943508103467 //-> arc : 0.110370 milliseconds
- Fetched data:4980514095087 //-> arc : 37005.991620 milliseconds
- Fetched sqles list:4980514152604 //-> arc : 0.057517 milliseconds
- Print data:4980515844896 //-> arc : 1.692292 milliseconds

So, why does the `getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql)` takes so slow...
The database is on localhost and executing the sql statement via phpMyAdmin goes much much quicker... `Showing rows 0 - 31 (32 total, Query took 0.1411 seconds.)`

Edit: Final SQL command executed is: `SELECT PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, PRODUCTS.NAME, PRODUCTS.CATEGORY, SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS UNITS, SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS * TICKETLINES.PRICE) AS TOTAL FROM RECEIPTS, TICKETS, TICKETLINES, PRODUCTS WHERE RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID AND TICKETS.ID = TICKETLINES.TICKET AND TICKETLINES.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID AND DATE(RECEIPTS.DATENEW)= CURDATE() AND NOT PRODUCTS.CATEGORY = "9286649c-00e1-428a-bd45-b47a1e0154b4" GROUP BY PRODUCTS.CATEGORY, PRODUCTS.NAME ORDER BY PRODUCTS.NAME`

Thank you,
Robin

Comment: Kindly share the final query generated and from what I see the problem is with your query, you need to use join rather than a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. One possibility is the query formation which could be slowing down the result
   The query should be if this format

   FROM RECEIPTS
   LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKETS
   ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKETLINES 
   ON TICKETS.ID = TICKETLINES.TICKET
   LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTS 
   ON TICKETLINES.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID
2. You can also try [indexing](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-an-index/) the columns which will make it run faster but use it after through evaluation

Comment: Thanks! The first one helped already a lot. From 37005.991620 milliseconds to 2443.94616 milliseconds, That's a factor of more than 10. What is so structurally different about the LEFT OUTER JOIN, compared to what i was doing before?